# playing a video by retrieving and manipulating frame by frame: is creating a new pixbuf at every frame the way to go or is there an easier way?

Tags: gtk, pygtk, gtk3, gdkpixbuf, pixbuf

using python3, gtk3. I am working on a computer vision application that needs to manipulate and display (playback) the frames from a video.

Currently, I create a new `Pixbuf` with the static method `new_from_data`, fed by a sequence of bytes created from a *numpy* array that contained the manipulated frame, and I am having performance problems, such as not being able to play the video at 20fps.

I wonder: is this the way to go for this kind of problem? Is creating a new Pixbuf for every frame relatively cheap or expensive? Should I use other methods, such as using `new_from_stream`? (not familiar with it)

Comment: Try GStreamer? I don't know how much work your setup would take...

Comment: the amount of work is not an issue

Comment: Yes, creating a new Pixbuf for every frame is very, very, expensive. Unfortunately I don't have a good answer for on-the-fly generated streaming video because it depends heavily on how you are generating the frames, and your other requirements, but this way is almost certainly not the best way.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an "easier" way, but if you're having performance issues, you should try using [Clutter](https://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/) via [Clutter-Gtk](https://developer.gnome.org/clutter-gtk/1.8/) which will use hardware acceleration to draw the frames.

You can create a [GtkClutterEmbed](https://developer.gnome.org/clutter-gtk/1.8/GtkClutterEmbed.html) widget, which will give you a ClutterStage which is a ClutterActor. Everytime you have a new frame, you can create a new ClutterImage and do [clutter_image_set_data()](https://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/ClutterImage.html#clutter-image-set-data) (which is just like new_from_data for the Pixbuf) and then set the ClutterContent of the ClutterActor (eg: the ClutterStage) to be this new ClutterImage.

This is how Gnome-Ring plays video, you can take a look at its [source code here](https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/ring-client-gnome/blob/master/src/video/video_widget.cpp#L562) for inspiration.